# is it possible in javascript get an element at the specified point if it is not on the top but is actually visible

Tags: javascript, css-position, visibility, absolute, topmost

test.html
There are 3 "layers" over the image

```
<img id=image width=200 height=200 src=http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/water_entertainment_motion_picture_165876.jpg>

<div id=dRed style="position:absolute; border: 2px solid red;
  left:50px; top:50px; width:100px; height:100px"></div>

<div id=dGreen style="position:absolute; border: 2px solid green;
  left:70px; top:70px; width:60px; height:60px"></div>

<div id=dBlue style="position:absolute; border: 2px solid blue;
  left:90px; top:90px; width:20px; height:20px"></div>
```

document.elementFromPoint(100,100) returns dBlue but user actually sees the image.
Is it possible to determine the image?

Answer (score 0):

As the [mozilla documentation said](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint), the method elementFromPoint:

> Returns the element from the document whose elementFromPoint method is
>   being called

Then I made a [sample](http://jsbin.com/ivEMAHI/2/edit?html,js,console,output) that use this concept.

```
<div id="divImg">
  <img id=image width=200 height=200 src="<image_url>">
</div>
```

I put the image inside the div `divImg`.

```
document.getElementById('divImg').addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
  console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.x,e.y).id);
});
```

I add a listener at the div, so I call the `elementFromPoint` when `mouseover` event of the `divImg` was trigger.

I hope this help you.

**UPDATE**: 
Looking closely at the specification of `elementFromPoint`, I see a css property used to disable the `pointer-events` of an element. Then to get only an element, you need to setup the other elements adding the css property `pointer-events:none`

Then you html will look:

```
<img id=image width=200 height=200 src=http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/water_entertainment_motion_picture_165876.jpg>

<div id=dRed style="pointer-events:none; position:absolute; border: 2px solid red;
  left:50px; top:50px; width:100px; height:100px"></div>

<div id=dGreen style="pointer-events:none; position:absolute; border: 2px solid green;
  left:70px; top:70px; width:60px; height:60px"></div>

<div id=dBlue style="pointer-events:none; position:absolute; border: 2px solid blue;
  left:90px; top:90px; width:20px; height:20px"></div>
```